# What Algorithms Exists for Finding a Representative Sample of the Local/Global Minima for a Function?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm working on a multi-objective optimization project, and I've stumbled across the need for an algorithm which given a function as an input which can be oracled any finite number of times (limited by computational power) can return an **evenly distributed sampling** of the locations of that function's local or global **minima**.

If you don't have a favorite language, I prefer Python and will port any recommendations to Python for my own use. Otherwise, any answer with or without code is more than acceptable.

This is similar to many questions that are more easily answered, so I have a few more clarifying details:

## 1. Example Usage/API

We'll define a function with known local minima to generate a simple test case.

```
import numpy as np

def f(x: np.ndarray):
    """If x has shape (2,) returns distance from line y=x"""
    return np.abs(np.diff(x))

def minima_sample(f, bounds, sample_size):
    """TODO"""
```

When we attempt to find 3 evenly-distributed, well-covered points in the unit square which are at the local (or global...it doesn't matter for my application) minima for `f` (which can be treated as an oracle), the best way to do so is to return the two endpoints of the line segment representing all the minima as well as the point directly in between. Similarly with 4 points.

```
>>> print(minima_sample(f, [(0,1), (0,1)], 3))
array([[0. , 0. ],
       [0.5, 0.5],
       [1. , 1. ]])

>>> print(minima_sample(f, [(0,1), (0,1)], 4))
array([[0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.33333333, 0.33333333],
       [0.66666667, 0.66666667],
       [1.        , 1.        ]])
```

## 2. Non-Answers

There are two classes of algorithms closely related to this problem:

#### 2.1 Local Solvers

Examples include gradient descent, a wide range of quasi-Newton methods, "blob-based" non-differentiable search operators, and so on. The neat thing is they can actually be used to answer this question relatively easily. Simply run the local solver at random starting points till the boundary of your solutions is approximately not increasing in size and continue running till you have enough points evenly distributed in that boundary. Focus efforts on empty spaces for a modicum of efficiency.

These can technically be used to build an answer, but IMO it is a fairly inefficient strategy. You need at least as many local minimization steps as you have points being requested (more if the function is ill-behaved), and all information is thrown away between local minimizations so that you cannot use the location of one minimum to guide the finding of another. Perhaps that is actually optimal, but I suspect something better exists.

#### 2.2 Global Solvers

Examples include basinhopping, simulated annealing, and so on. On the surface, they might seem like the right approach since they examine a large number of local minima and eventually settle on the smallest of those. One could simply return a suitable subset of the obtained local minima. By design, however, they choose local minima in a way which is likely to step toward a global minimum. By definition, this attempts to bias the search and samples the local minima unevenly.

## 3. Additional Information

Out of personal curiosity I'm interested in any algorithm you think might be applicable. As a practical matter, the efficiency of an optimization routine is heavily tied to how tailored it is for a particular problem. The particular function I have in mind has a quite a few constraints and special properties that might make make a difference:

1. Ignoring numerical errors, the function I want to optimize has the property that all local minima are in fact global minima.
2. Except for some pathological inputs, the function I want to optimize has the additional property that the global minimum is 0.
3. The function can be assumed to be an infinitely-differentiable scalar function of n variables (represented as a flat numpy array if a particular programming language is needed).
4. Evaluating the function, its Jacobian, and the product of its Hessian with any vector can all be done in O(n^2) time.
5. Evaluating the Jacobian requires roughly 3x the time for a single function evaluation.
6. Evaluating the Hessian-vector product requires roughly 2x the time for a single Jacobian evaluation
7. Evaluating higher-ordered differential forms is prohibitively expensive (for now...I think automatic differentiation has that particular problem somewhat solved if I try a little harder/longer).
8. Except in pathological cases, the minima lie on unions of low-dimensional manifolds. This is something I expect to matter a great deal since it gives quite a bit of information about where to search for new minima given the locations of old minima.
9. The function is bounded on whichever bounded domain is chosen, but that bound is not necessarily known ahead of time.
10. For larger problems with 10,000+ inputs, some of the intermediate calculations tend to add numerical instability. In those cases, none of the quantities I mentioned (function, Jacobian, Hessian) can be known to more than 5 or 6 decimal places, so ideally any solution would not require higher accuracy.
11. The intended application has tens of thousands of inputs and requires a sampling with 50-2000 points covering the local minima.
12. A side effect of the computation is that for each function evaluation we get a useful representation of it in a dimension-reduced space. This may not matter, but it could be useful to use a low-dimensional (2-10D) representation for computations like proximity rather than the 10,000+ dimensional input.
13. In case it matters, the function whose minima we desire is the smallest of the potentially non-zero singular values of the Jacobian of a particular m-dimensional function of the same n-dimensional inputs we are optimizing over. The reduced space mentioned above is the output of that m-dimensional function.

## 4. Current Attempts and Ideas

- I have the random restart method mentioned in **2.1** implemented currently. It technically works, but it is slower than I would like. It also isn't elegant or satisfying from an algorithms perspective.
- The random restart method doesn't sample uniformly, but by modifying the starting locations to attempt to push the boundaries of existing solutions and fill in the voids in those solutions (using the reduced space for proximity calculations), a reasonable covering can be obtained. Counting Jacobians and Hessians, this uses ~5 function evaluations per sample point for simple problems and ~80 for complicated problems. The goal would be to use some of the extra information we are currently discarding to reduce that ~80 down to something more manageable. I expect a maximum speedup then of ~16x (or on the other side of the coin the ability to work with larger problems).
- One thought I've had has been to find a single local minimum and then "follow" the manifold it happens to be on by moving in directions with a directional derivative of 0 (since the local and global minimums are all 0). This is sort of easy enough to implement for 1D manifolds, but I haven't been able to come up with a satisfactory way to handle more complicated search spaces without doubling back.
- It strikes me that evolutionary algorithms for the population with a newton-based local search component for individuals might be effective. The relationship to random search and extreme sensitivity to parameters that evolutionary algorithms typically have has left me wary.

## 5. Finally

Is there a standard way of solving such a problem? If not, is there a short/long list of applicable algorithms whose pros and cons I could weigh? My Google-foo has come up short, and my initial hunches aren't yielding great results. Is there anything else I should be considering as I tackle this? Even book/reference/blog/podcast recommendations would be better than nothing.

Thank you in advance for your efforts.

Comment: Depending on your perspective, [cs.se] and/or [stats.se] might yield better results, if you don't get anything here.

Comment: Are you sure you can guarantee that all local minima are global minima (unless there are large "flat regions"). If it is true it means that running your local solvers from any starting point would normally find the global minima. Have you considered the non-smoothness if the smallest svd switches at a potential local minima?

Comment: @AakashM I appreciate the observations. I've also seen reasonable success with math-related algorithm questions at [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) with a slight re-wording to fit their guidelines. I'll move it if needed.

Comment: @HansOlsson I based that statement on the fact that after hundreds of thousands of runs on simulated data I have never observed a local solver to converge somewhere other than a global minimum (within the preset tolerance of it anyway). It might not be true, but it seems true enough for my use case.

Comment: @HansOlsson Also, I've considered the non-smoothness of the smallest svd switching and chosen to ignore it for now. With probability 1 that behavior never happens, and nearby such switches the function is nicely behaved. If necessary, working with a non-differentiable solver to deal with kinks is an option.